# Make button hit area larger in jquery mobile

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

Is there anyway to make the button hit area larger in jquery mobile. i have two buttons in the header of the app and if i don't touch theme right in the middle they won't work.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to expand hit area around button is to add invisible wrapper around button with some padding. Then attach tap event to the wrapper and trigger tap event on button itself.

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4m9q/3/)

html

```
<div id='button-wrap' style='padding: 20px;'>
    <a id='button' href="#" data-role="button" >Button</a>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('#button-wrap').on('tap', function(e){
    $(this).find('a').trigger('tap');
});

$('#button').on('tap', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('tapped!');
});
```